# Website gets weird crop on mobile after using <meta name="viewport"> with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I noticed that my website is hard to read on mobile devices and I found out I should put `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
into the `<head>` of the document.

I did that and now some weird cropping is happening to all of my containers.

Here is a **screenshot**. 
[I feel like navbar is longer than it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pRz7.png)

Note that navbar fills whole width of screen and containers don't. This happens only when I hold my phone in "portrait" mode. Landscape works fine.

Any idea what could cause this?
edit: I feel like the containers are scaling fine. The navbar stays and 578px and wont go lover. The difference of space between the size of navbar and containers results in that "white space".

And this is how my `<html>`s look like. Sorry for non-english language :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Vlastys</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Megrim" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--Bootstrap here-->
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling.css">

        <!-- Bootstrap javascript and jquery here-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>     
</head>
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60"> 
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="navbarID">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#top">DOMŮ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#info">INFO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tvorba">TVORBA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#spoluprace">SPOLUPRÁCE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#kontakt">KONTAKT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Konec navigátoru -->

    <div class="container-fluid bg-1"  id="top">
        <h1> VLASTYS </h1>
        <img src="img/vodnar.png" id="vodnar" alt="Vodnar">


    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid bg-2 text-center" id="info">
        <h2> INFO </h2>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
        exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
        exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
        exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center" id="tvorba">
        <h3> TVORBA </h3>
        </br>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <img src="img/placeholder.png" class="img-responsive img-circle" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
    <img src="img/placeholder.png" class="img-responsive img-circle" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <img src="img/placeholder.png" class="img-responsive img-circle" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <img src="img/placeholder.png" class="img-responsive img-circle" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <!-- spolupráce -->
    <div class="container-fluid bg-4 text-center" id="spoluprace">
    <h2> SPOLUPRÁCE </h2>
    </br>
        </br>
            </br>
                </br>
                    </br>
                        </br>
                            </br>
                                </br>
                                    </br>
                                        </br>

    </div>

    <!-- Kontakt -->
    <div class="container-fluid bg-2 text-center" id="kontakt">
    <h3> KONTAKT </h3>
            </br>
            </br>
                </br>
                    </br>
                        </br>
                            </br>
                                </br>
                                    </br>
                                        </br>
    </div>

    <footer class="container-fluid bg-4 text-center">
        <p> Made by @vrerabek </p>
    </footer>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scroll.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the entire html for that page.

Comment: Hey, sure. one sec

Comment: why do you have all those </br> tags?

Comment: It is just for testing purposes. It's basically empty div so far. :)